# GitKraken: Error when pushing many files (Chunk Header Problem)

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitlab, gitkraken

I am using GitKraken 7.4.0. on Windows 10 and with Unity 2019.3 and we use GitLab. Everything usually works fine when pushing and pulling commits but I currently have a lot of PNGs due to animations that I need to commit. Anytime I try to commit these, I get "failed to write chunk header: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response."

This happened before when I needed to commit a couple of voice lines. If I reduce the files to fewer commits, it works fine. For example: If I try to push 200 PNGs (they're not big, around 600kb) I get the error. But if I commit four times with 50 PNGs, it works.

Is there a way to fix this, because breaking up hundreds of PNGs every time is very cumbersome. I already thought of uploading the files to Google Drive so the others can download them there, but that is equally annoying.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why not log a bug with gitkraken, or use git commands directly and work out if its your server config

Comment: Haven't thought of logging a bug, I will do that. Thank you for the suggestion! I'm no programmer and using the interface of GitKraken is as much as I know about git, so I don't know how to use git commands directly, unfortunately.

Comment: You should probably start to use [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com) there are already ready to use `.gitattributes` example files for Unity projects e.g. [this one](https://gist.github.com/nemotoo/b8a1c3a0f1225bb9231979f389fd4f3f) .. in general this seems GitKraken specific as we are using Gitlab for Unity projects and together with Git LFS never had this issue with using SourceTree or directly the Git bash ...

Comment: @derHugo That solved the issue for me, thank you so much! I installed Git and activated LFS in GitKraken, used your settings file, and voila, the commit goes through without a problem :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same behavior, and it seems that the issue is caused by GitKraken.
I am using GitKraken (8.8.0) and I don't use Unity.

I don't know what causes the issue, but my solution was to push from the terminal with:

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @derHugo I managed to solve the issue. If anyone else is having this issue and is also using Unity, here is how you can resolve it:

Make sure you have Git downloaded and installed. Minimum:

```
Git version 2.3+
LFS version 2.0.1+
```

Now activate LFS in your GitKraken settings. Find your .gitattributes file and copy-paste [these](https://gist.github.com/nemotoo/b8a1c3a0f1225bb9231979f389fd4f3f) contents into it, save it. It should work now.

Check out the GitKraken Documentation for more details:

https://support.gitkraken.com/git-workflows-and-extensions/intro-and-requirements/#git-lfs-requirements

https://support.gitkraken.com/git-workflows-and-extensions/intro-and-requirements/#git-lfs-requirements